# iRobot Create 2 Question

Tags: irobot-create

With the Create 2 iRobot if it is already moving backwards (**with its bump sensors in the front of it**) how would I code it to sense that it is hitting something on its back side with only using the create's sensors?

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no sensors on the back, its probably best to only back up a short distance and then make a 180 degree turn.

The only other way I can think of is to monitor the left and right motor current (packet 54 & 55) to see if its above the normal level assuming its backed into something and bogging down

Frank